# Is "www" just another subdomain?

Tags: dns, subdomain

I have a PHP application that must differentiate between different subdomains, and trying to better understand domains and subdomains.  When I look at my GoDaddy Zone File, I see the following.  This makes me think that my main domain `mydomain.com` points to `123.45.678`, and several other subdomains such as `ftp` and `www` point to `@` which in turn points to my main domain `123.45.678`, yet include their respective subdomain.  Am I mistaken?  I read http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=470669 which is rather entertaining, however, never concluded the correct interpretation.  Thank you

```
A (Host) 
Host    Points To
@       123.45.678

CName (Alias)
Host    Points To
ftp     @   
www     @
```

Answer (score 0):

The '@' refers to the origin (your domain name, for example: mydomain.com) in the zone file. All the other records are hosts in that domain. For example 'www.mydomain.com' doesn't refer to a sub-domain, but rather a host in the 'mydomain.com' domain. By stating that they point to @ (origin), this means all these 'hosts' are actually the same server. In essence your zone file says that you are running your FTP and web servers on the same physical host. If they were running on different machines, the @ in those lines would be replaced by the actual IP addresses of those machines.

TL;DR: the 'www' and 'ftp' entries are hosts in your domain, not sub-domains.